# MATLAB: Saving a slice through volumetric data to an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, data-visualization

I have a 3D stack of bwlabeln'ed data (128 by 128 by 128). Is there a way to cut a slice through it (as in MATLAB slice(...)) and save the resulting image to a matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function that may be of use is:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32032-extract-slice-from-volume

for other solutions, see:
[Extract arbitrarily rotated plane of data from 3D array as 2D array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9083351/extract-arbitrarily-rotated-plane-of-data-from-3d-array-as-2d-array/9098349#9098349)

Comment: Lovely! Will test and confirm.
Also, do you know if there's a way to prevent the popup figure window from appearing? (possibly an artifact of hsp = surf(...))

Comment: yes you are right, it is because of 'surf'.  I should update that section of code... in the mean time, a quick fix would be to add a set(gcf,'Visible','off'); or just close that window once hsp is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of slice? Along one dimension e.g. z=5 you can use M(:,:,5). For diagonal slices you have to use some advanced method (interpolation).

Comment: I'll need diagonal slices, i.e. with a given normal vector and pivot point.